# Selecting multiple items by default in sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice (symfony)

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

Using Symfony and Doctrine, I have a multi-select list box.  The multiple default values need to be generated based on a Doctrine query.

```
$this->setWidgets(array(
  'folders' => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array(
    'model' => 'FolderItem',
    'order_by' => array('name', 'asc'),
    'multiple' => true,
    'query' => FolderItemTable::getUserInstance($user),
  ))
));
```

This gets me a list of all my folder items; however, I want them pre-selected by a list of Folders.  For example, if I have `Folder 1` containing `item a` `item b` and `item c`  and `Folder 2` containing `item d` and `item e`; if `Folder 1` is passed in I want `item a` `item b` and `item c` to be selected, but I want `item d` and `item e` in the list but not selected (but selectable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are using a Doctrine relation to populate the list you can do something like this in your form class

```
  $this->setDefault('folders', $this->object->Users->getPrimaryKeys());
```

You can also pass an array with the values to be selected

```
  $this->setDefault('folders', array(125,2049,12));
```